# Markers on hover in choropleth maps

Tags: python, choropleth, folium

I have tried to plot a map using folium to show the distribution of a metric over various states in the US. I have used popups using folium. But I am unable to use popups in folium map (choropleth).

This is the code:

```
import folium

state_geo = r'data/us-states.json'
map = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=3)
map.choropleth(geo_path=state_geo, data=state_data,
             columns=['State', 'Value'],
             key_on='feature.id',
             fill_color='YlGn', fill_opacity=0.9, line_opacity=0.2,
             legend_name='Data')
map.save('data.html')
display(map)
```

I need to know how to bring popup values when I hover over each state in the map.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a nice answer to your question either, but for now I hack with `folium.Circle`

```
for idx, row in state_geo.iterrows():
    popup = idx
    folium.CircleMarker([row['latitude'], row['longitude']], popup=popup,
                        radius=1, color='white').add_to(map)
```

This does not give the nice hovering effect you are searching for but the closest best quick thing I could find - a popup with a mouse. Not as aesthetic as I would like, but works for now.